# Python3, subprocess, always get nonetype error

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am new to python. I am currently porting our python2 code to python 3. `subprocess` does not work me. I always get the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

when I call `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.check_output`, etc.

Example:

```
$python3

Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 26 2018, 19:50:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import subprocess

subprocess.run(['echo','123'])

123

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 405, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 849, in communicate
    return (stdout.decode(), stderr.decode())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your Python installation. I ran the same exact code using same version of Python and it got run successfully.

```
~|⇒ python3
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 26 2018, 19:50:54)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['echo', '123'])
123
CompletedProcess(args=['echo', '123'], returncode=0)
```

Try to uninstall and install Python again, that might help.

Comment: The uninstall and reinstall of Python 3.6 solved the problem.  Thanks!